# Изменение размеров кнопки(JButton) при добавлении символов в нее?

Tags: java

Как изменить размеры кнопки(JButton) при добавлении символов в нее? Компоновка null! Сейчас при добавлении символов она добавляет где-то три символа, а затем появляются ... и все остальные добавляемые cимволы мы не видим.Может надо какую-то настройку кнопки сделать...

Comment: Вопрос довольно туманный. Поведение swing-компонентов, в т. ч. размер, определяется множеством разных факторов - владельцем, его `Layout`om, настройками... Вы ничего не сказали об этом. Скорее всего, вам надо разбираться с лэйаутом.

Answer (score 2):

Обычно управление положением и размеров компонентов в контейнере осуществляет установленный в контейнере `LayoutManager`. В вашем случае когда менеджер компоновки является `null`, то управлять этим некому. Следовательно размером и положением компонентов нужно управлять вручную.

Например можно дополнить код который изменяет текст на кнопке кодом который будет увеличивать ширину кнопки:

```
JButton btn = new JButton("AAA");
        btn.addActionListener(
           ae -> {btn.setText(btn.getText()+"A");
                  Dimension dim = btn.getSize(); 
                  btn.setSize(dim.width + 10, dim.height);}
        );
```

Или же создать свой класс кнопки наследовавшись от JButton и переопределить метод `setText`:

```
public void setText(String text) {
   super(text);
   Dimension dim = getSize(); 
   setSize(text.length * 10, dim.height);
}
```

Но правильнее всего будет не изобретать велосипедов, а использовать подходящий компоновщик.

Answer (score 2):

После добавления символов надо писать

```
button1.setSize(button1.getPreferredSize());
button1.setBounds(button1.getX(),button1.getY(),button1.getWidth(), button1.getHeight());
```